# Linux driver type for point to point communications

Tags: c, linux

I have two processors that are connected to each other through a serial interface. One processor is running a bare metal loop, the other is running linux. To simplify the interface protocol I have created an Ethernet like frame that is used to create different message types. Some of the messages are small, less than 200 bytes, while others are much larger, close to 100 MBytes. The larger messages are broken up into a bunch of packets similar to the TCP/IP stack.

I started out with a poll loop running in user space. This required a dedicated process to handle receiving and sending of packets. Messages to the bare metal device could be initiated from several different programs. Some of these programs are intended to run for the duration of system power, while others are one off programs triggered by the user that terminate shortly after an action is complete. The bare metal device is expecting to receive an entire message as contiguous packets. Therefore, when sending a message a process must have complete control over the transmitter.

I am trying to simplify the interface and possibly speed it up as we have an interrupt signal available by attempting to create a kernel driver. Currently I have come up with the design to create a character driver in unison with a shared library. The shared library would handle the breaking of the data up into packets and forming the data into frames. It would also interface with the driver and handle the semaphore. When the process invokes the shared library open function, it will also create a mailbox structure in the driver to store any received messages for the given PID. The bare metal device has no real memory management and I don't attend on adding any so there can be no interleaving of messages.

My first question is that I believe I need this library and cannot do everything in the driver because I have to deal with 100 MByte data buffers coming in from userspace. The library functions would be able to take a descriptor and transfer the data to the driver using a more reasonable buffer size. Is this a correct assumption?

My second question is should I be trying to use a net device instead? I have more experience with character devices so that was what I started with.

Comment: Please post the code.  How are we to help you with a runtime problem if we do not have access to the code?

Comment: There is no code. It is a design question, meant to  drive the direction of the code. The only code that exists is the old userspace code, which is irrelevant to the questions being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest each new process gets a thread in the 'open' processing

The serial device driver gets a length from each call to write, and can use the length to malloc enough memory to hold the message.

Suggest the device driver be written in layers,

```
1layer to handle the actual serial hardware  
1layer to handle the user interface (open, close, write entry points at a minimum)  
1layer to handle packet formation. 
1layer to handle sequencing of the messages
```

the serial device driver would be easiest if it caused the user process to block on a write, however, that may have serious repercussions on overall system performance, so the write operation may malloc a suitable memory segment, keep unique info when the serial device driver is 'open'd to enable the sequencing layer to not intermix the messages actually sent.

the serial device driver probably should perform the actual I/O via an interrupt (most serial devices have a internal buffer to minimize the total number of interrupt events to be handled.

Comment: How would this design handle large writes, say 100MBytes in size? I liked to avoid having to have two large buffers, one for userspace and one in the kernel.